# EntityStructureWrapper for file field is not being inflated properly while iterating

Tags: 7, entities, files

While trying to interate over file filed values, EMW cannot being created properly. using `isset()` for not iniated fields and then trying to set them is not helping.

I get the error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   field_discipline. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line
>   335 of
>   /var/www/siradisisporlar.com/sites/all/modules/ssbasic/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Note that file wrapper here is EntityStructureWrapper and node wrapper is EntityDrupalWrapper.

All properties of other entity reference fields, etc are being reached properly.

`$filew::data` is array and it has fid where `$nodew::data` is a proper node object.

```
mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  //.... ..... $nodew is node wrapper
  foreach ($nodew->field_media as $delta => $filew) {
    $a = $filew->field_taxonomy_entity_reference->value(); //error here
    $b = $nodew->field_taxonomy_entity_reference->value();
    $c = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));
    $filew->field_taxonomy_entity_reference = $c; //error here
    $filew->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, you cannot reach other fields of the file object here, like alt text or owner.

Comment: `$filew->getIdentifier()` also comes null.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I am posting a very bad workaround for future reference. Anybody who can improve this is welcome:

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  //copy terms
  $nodew = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  //@todo this is not cool, figure it out
  foreach ($nodew->field_media->value() as $delta => $files) {
    $filew = entity_metadata_wrapper('file', $files['fid']);
    $filew->field_taxonomy_entity_reference = array_unique(array_merge($filew->field_taxonomy_entity_reference, $nodew->field_taxonomy_entity_reference));
    $filew->save();

  }
}
```